# Unable to install APC and XDebug in Vagrant VM

Tags: php, apc, vagrant, pecl

I followed several tutorials and guides concerning Vagrant and Chef Solo, but I am running into problems when I want to provision my Precise64 VM using Chef Solo. After installing PHP5.3 and PECL and PEAR the recipe needs to install APC, however it is unable to find the package although APC is available on PECL. This is the message I get.

```
RuntimeError
------------
Package apc not found in either PEAR or PECL.

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/php/providers/pear.rb:259:in `pecl?'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/php/providers/pear.rb:107:in     `load_current_resource'

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/web-app/recipes/webserver.rb

 17: package "libpcre3-dev"
 18: php_pear "apc" do
 19:   action :install
 20: end
 21:
```

First I thought my PECL and PEAR were not up to date, however they are updated beforehand using the following:

```
# update the main channels
php_pear_channel 'pear.php.net' do
  action :update
end

php_pear_channel 'pecl.php.net' do
  action :update
end
```

**EDIT**:
After `vagrant ssh` into my box and running `sudo pecl install apc` it seems to resolve the package just fine. Something is going wrong in the recipe.
I've tried the above method on Debian Squeeze 64 and Ubuntu Server Precise 64 FYI

**EDIT2**:
I've set up a new box, using Precise32 and a brand new Vagrantfile and recipe using `knife` and I get the same error. I tried installing XDebug using PECL also, but I get a very non-sensical error.

I've created a Gist with my configuration and the error messages I get, and hopefully people can see whats wrong. As far as I can see the `php_pear` provider of the `php`-recipe is broken.

You can see the Gist here: https://gist.github.com/4492004

It is driving me completely nuts... the simplest things won't work with Chef-solo and when following the most basic tutorials online I get all sorts of errors. It's infuriating.

**EDIT3**
When visiting https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php you'll see that the recipe `php::module_apc` is deprecated and that a PEAR/PECL or package install is better. I was wondering how they implemented the `php::module_apc` recipe and found this (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php/blob/master/recipes/module_apc.rb):

```
case node['platform_family']
when "rhel", "fedora"
   %w{ httpd-devel pcre pcre-devel }.each do |pkg|
       package pkg do
           action :install
       end
   end
   php_pear "apc" do
       action :install
       directives(:shm_size => "128M", :enable_cli => 0)
   end
when "debian"
   package "php-apc" do
       action :install
   end
end
```

So clearly they now something is wrong when using the `php_pear` command when using Debian/Ubuntu but it's nowhere documented. Seeing as that PEAR/PECL was the most standard way to install PHP add-ons I was focussing on getting that to work, however seeing this I think I'll have to refer to using the `package` command.
I'll ask the Opscode people why they make the exception for Debian.

**THE FINAL CHAPTER**
Great succes! Using the `package` command it was a breeze. However, installing packages using PECL/PEAR seems to be problematic in Debian using Chef. So the problem remains, a workaround is found (which is actually the normal way of operating for Debian although the documentation on Github suggests otherwise)

Comment: The error message tells you what is happening, so I wonder why you ask. We can't tell you more than the error message is telling you already. Also if you use some other system like ubuntu, does it work then? Otherwise I'd contact Precision64 support first, never heard of them, so probably they are very special. ;)

Comment: @hakre If the message was clear and the solution simple (e.g. the package is not there) I would not ask this question. The package is obviously there, so something else is going wrong and I can't figure it out. But thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: Okay, suggesting to do that manual would have been the next thing, but you edited, you did that already. Could it be that the installation command is not running as root? Maybe some missing configuration in chef?

Comment: Every command is being run as user vagrant which has sudo rights. Don't know how to change it to root.

Comment: sudo rights is enough. that's also how I know it, too, so I really wonder what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Using capital seems to install it via php_pear

```
php_pear 'APC' do
  action :install
end
```

EDIT:
In the end I had to install it via package because using php_pear would create the ini file with capitalized directives and it would not be read properly. Something like `APC.shm_size` is not valid.

I ended up doing something like this:

```
package "php-apc"
template "#{node['php']['ext_conf_dir']}/apc.ini" do
  source "apc.ini.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
  variables(:name => "apc", :extensions => ["apc.so"], :directives => {"shm_size" => "256"})
  action action
end
```

I created my own apc.ini.erb template file:

```
; configuration for php <%= @name %> module
<% @extensions.each do |filepath, zend| -%>
extension=<%= filepath %>
<% end -%>
<% @directives.each do |k,v| -%>
<%= "#{@name}.#{k}=\"#{v}\"" %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue on centos 5 with vagrant and chef. I put some debugging code into the php cookbook and saw that is was trying to run this command
    pecl -d preferred_state=stable search -c pecl.php.net APC'

The out put that i recieved was

```
Retrieving data...0%.Invalid xml downloaded from "http://pecl.php.net/rest/p/dom_varimport/info.xml": XML Error: 'Invalid character' on line '13'
```

Turned out I was running a really old version of php pear. I fixed it by running the following command

```
pear upgrade -f PEAR
```

Comment: Imho, this should be a complete new question, but thanks for the answer, helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, I solved it with the following modifications. Have you tried it ?

os: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

chef-solo: 10.16.6

success: php_pear "APC" do

problem: php_pear "apc" do

It seems that php recipe is not ignore the case.

But I have another problem that configure option is incorret. "-e" is assigned to the first option. (It occurs only in ubuntu. It does not occur in centos6.)

```
chef-solo(log_level :debug)
running: /tmp/pear/temp/APC/configure --enable-apc-debug=-e --enable-apc-filehits=no --enable-apc-spinlocks=no --enable-apc-memprotect=no --enable-apc-pthreadmutex=no --enable-apc-pthreadrwlocks=yes

pecl install apc
running: /tmp/pear/temp/APC/configure --enable-apc-debug=no --enable-apc-filehits=no --enable-apc-spinlocks=no --enable-apc-memprotect=no --enable-apc-pthreadmutex=no --enable-apc-pthreadrwlocks=yes
```

Comment: The "-e" problem seems to be affected by "echo -e" in "cookbooks/php/providers/pear.rb" (line 146). https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php (release v1.1.4)

Comment: In ubuntu, the "echo -e" isn't /bin/echo but Dash echo. Dash echo doesn't support for -e option. I suspect that it's replaced with printf.(echo -e \"\\r\" => printf \"\\r\")